# Relocating the cursor in Google Sheets using scripts

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Hopefully this is something simple that I've overlooked.

I am attempting to populate a sheet with the serial numbers, asset tags and MAC addresses of new stock using a barcode scanner.
The code below works fine so far but my last struggle is making the **cursor return to cell C2** after updating the sheet.
I have commented out the setCursor line as it produces the error:
"ReferenceError: "setCursor" is not defined."

I don't understand what it is I need to do to make this work!
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
   function bookingIn() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet ();  
  var source1 = ss.getRange ("BOOKING_IN!C2");
  var source2 = ss.getRange ("BOOKING_IN!C3");
  var source3 = ss.getRange ("BOOKING_IN!C4");
  var destSheet = ss.getSheetByName("BOOKING_IN");

  var dest1 = destSheet.getRange(destSheet.getLastRow()+1,1);
  var dest2 = destSheet.getRange(destSheet.getLastRow()+1,2);
  var dest3 = destSheet.getRange(destSheet.getLastRow()+1,3);

  source1.copyTo (dest1, {contentsOnly: true});
  source2.copyTo (dest2, {contentsOnly: true});
  source3.copyTo (dest3, {contentsOnly: true});

  source1.clear ();
  source2.clear ();    

  //setCursor("BOOKING_IN!C2")




}
```

Comment: Do you need [tag:excel] here? Excel is using [tag:vba], not [tag:javascript]

Comment: Good point!  Noob error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a syntax for selecting a range in [google-spreadsheets](/questions/tagged/google-spreadsheets):

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

 var range = sheet.getRange("A1:D4");
 sheet.setActiveRange(range);
```

See [The Reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#setActiveRange(Range)) for [[image]google-apps-script](/questions/tagged/google-apps-script)

Comment: Fixed by adding these two lines:

var restart = ss.getRange("C2");
ss.setActiveRange(restart);

Massive thanks!